# Install noveau driver but keeps nvidia driver installed in Arch Linux

Tags: drivers, arch-linux, nvidia-graphics-card

I've read [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nouveau#Keep_NVIDIA_driver_installed) manual to do this. It said I have to comment out `blacklist nouveau` in `/etc/modprobe.d/nouveau_blacklist.conf` file. But, there's no such a file there. So how can I do this?

Comment: Can you run ls in your modprobe.d directory and paste the output in your question?  Another option would be to uninstall the nvidia driver if your attempting to switch permanently

Comment: It's empty. `ls /etc/modprobe.d/`

Answer (score 0):

Create a file in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ called 20-nouveau.conf

```
Section "Device" 
    Identifier "Nvidia card" 
    Driver "nouveau" 
EndSection
```

However it is highly recommended to just uninstall the proprietary driver if you want to use nouveau.